# Loop over letters in a string that contains the alphabet to determine which are missing from a dictionary

Tags: python

I am very new to python and trying to find the solution to this for a class.

I need the function missing_letters to take a list, check the letters using histogram and then loop over the letters in alphabet to determine which are missing from the input parameter.  Finally I need to print the letters that are missing, in a string.

```
 alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"   

    test = ["one","two","three"]

    def histogram(s):
        d = dict() 
        for c in s:
            if c not in d:
                d[c] = 1
            else:
                d[c] += 1
        return d

    def missing_letter(s):
        for i in s:
            checked = (histogram(i))
```

As you can see I haven't gotten very far, at the moment missing_letters returns

```
{'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'e': 1}
{'t': 1, 'w': 1, 'o': 1}
{'t': 1, 'h': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 2}
```

I now need to loop over alphabet to check which characters are missing and print.  Any help and direction will be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: It seems like there are no missing letters at all?

Comment: I didn't understand. you want to list all the alphabet letters that are not present in the string? So if the string is `one`, you want to print all letters except [`o`, `n`, `e`]?

Comment: What should be the output for this?

Comment: from string import ascii_lowercase

Comment: The histogram function can be optimized, but is ok. The second function can be solved looping the alphabet: `[letter for letter in alphabet if letter not in s]`

Comment: `set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')-set('one')` ?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? looping over the alphabet? checking for missing characters? *saving* missing characters?  How does `histogram` fit into the *algorithm* of `missing_letters`?  Maybe explain in words what your process is or should be for `missing_letters`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It sounds like you have an idea of what you need to do to *solve* `missing_letters` but it doesn't look like you have made an attempt to solve it. [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Thanks @wwii.  I am having trouble making the loop over the alphabet compare with the dictionary that histogram is returning.  Missing_letters should take a list, find the letters for each string in that list using histogram, then print a line for each string such as, "one is missing abcdfghijklmpqrstuvwxyz"

Comment: Perhaps you are having trouble because you haven't tried anything yet?  It looks like you know how to write a for loop and `histogram` works so you just need to work out the logic and put it all together.

Comment: Thanks @wwii I understand why this  wasn't the right way to tackle this solution.  I appreciate your input and will ask better questions in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use set functions in python, which is very fast and efficient:

```
alphabet = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
s1 = 'one'
s2 = 'two'
s3 = 'three'

list_of_missing_letters = set(alphabet) - set(s1) - set(s2) - set(s3)

print(list_of_missing_letters)
```

Or like this:

```
from functools import reduce

alphabet = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
list_of_strings = ['one', 'two', 'three']

list_of_missing_letters = set(alphabet) - \
    reduce(lambda x, y: set(x).union(set(y)), list_of_strings)

print(list_of_missing_letters)
```

---

Or using your own `histogram` function:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

test = ["one", "two", "three"]


def histogram(s):
    d = dict()
    for c in s:
        if c not in d:
            d[c] = 1
        else:
            d[c] += 1
    return d


def missing_letter(t):
    test_string = ''.join(t)
    result = []
    for l in alphabet:
        if l not in histogram(test_string).keys():
            result.append(l)
    return result

print(missing_letter(test))
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'p', 'q', 's', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Comment: Yes Amir, I appreciate your help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

words = ["one","two","three"]

letters = [l.lower() for w in words for l in w]

# all letters not in alphabet
letter_str = "".join(x for x in ascii_lowercase if x not in letters)
```

Output:

```
'abcdfgijklmpqsuvxyz'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not the easiest question to understand, but from what I can gather you require all the letters of the alphabet not in the input to be returned in console.

So a loop as opposed to functions which have been already shown would be:

```
def output():
    output = ""    
    for i in list(alphabet):
        for key in checked.keys():
            if i != key:
               if i not in list(output):
                  output += i
    print(output)
```

*Sidenote: Please either make checked a global variable or put it outside of function so this function can use it*